# On the lack of consistency in aircraft-specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Aviation SE has both tag [a-6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-6) and tag [douglas-a-4-skyhawk](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/douglas-a-4-skyhawk), for instance. Why not have tag [grumman-a-6-intruder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grumman-a-6-intruder) instead of tag [a-6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-6)? Why not have [a-4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-4) instead of [douglas-a-4-skyhawk](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/douglas-a-4-skyhawk)? Why not have tag [grumman-a-6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grumman-a-6) with synonym [intruder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intruder)? Could this community please attempt to arrive at a decision on what convention to use when naming aircraft-specific tags?

Using the succinct tag [a-6](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-6) (or the slightly less succinct tag [a-6-intruder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-6-intruder))  would allow the clustering of all existing tags for attack aircraft in the `Watched Tags` box. On the other hand, using the least succinct tag [grumman-a-6-intruder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grumman-a-6-intruder) would allow the clustering of tags by manufacturer rather than by role. Omitting the manufacturer may be desirable because many manufacturers have been merged into behemoths like Boeing and Lockheed Martin.